# Can't sniff / initiate DHCP renew

Tags: linux, debian, dhcp, tcpdump

I am running

```
 sudo tcpdump -i enp0s31f6 -n port 67 and port 68
```

on one terminal and running

```
 sudo dhclient -r
```

on another.

During this, I see nothing on first terminal.

What I am doing wrong?

---

Both terminals are on the same machine. I wish to sniff DHCP communication on the same machine, which does it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the port `68` on the client (`lsof -i :68`), the command should be :

```
sudo tcpdump -i enp0s31f6 -n port 68
```

You can use `dhcpdump` instead: `dhcpdump -i enp0s31f6`.

```
man dhcpdump:

This command parses the output of tcpdump to display the dhcp-packets
for easier checking and debugging.
```

Comment: `dhcpdump` is a good suggestion, however you have not explained *why* to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not seeing anything because there is a mistake on your `tcpdump` boolean logic BPF rules.

It should be:

```
sudo tcpdump -i enp0s31f6 -n port 67 or port 68
```

and not as you are doing:

```
 sudo tcpdump -i enp0s31f6 -n port 67 and port 68
```

In the first instruction, you are listening to either port 67 OR port 68 (one or the other).

In the second instruction, you are asking for a rule where ports are both 67 AND 68 *at the same time*, and thus seeing no packets.